# Initializing const variable

Tags: c, initialization, constants, const-correctness

Can we initialize a const variable as follows

```
int var1 = 10;
const int var2 = var1;
```

Will this cause any warning/error in any compiler ?

Comment: Is it really called a const variable? That feels like an oxymoron.

Comment: @David: There is no notion of "variable" in either C or C++ standards. The technical term is "const object", I think.

Comment: @Armen: in fact C++ does contain a notion of a "variable", 3/4: "A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of an object. The variable's name denotes the object". So a variable is a named object, regardless of whether it's const or not. Or, if we want to get all Goedel-Escher-Bach, the variable isn't explicitly stated to *be* the object, but it is a thing that has the same name as the object does! The C99 standard uses the noun "variable" in notes, apparently with a similar meaning.

Answer (score 14):

Depends where the code is.

If it's inside a function, so that `var1` and `var2` are automatics, then yes this is fine. `var2` is only initialized by copying `var1` anyway, so the fact that `var1` can be modified later has no bearing on the fact that `var2` can't.

If it's in file scope, so that `var1` and `var2` are statics, then no it is not fine. A const integer object at file scope must be initialized with a value certain to be known at compile time (in C++ this is called an "integer constant expression", I forget whether that's the exact C terminology too). In this case, you might think that because there's no code in between the two definitions, the value of `var1` would be known at compile time to be `10`, but because the type is non-const, the standard forbids it anyway. You can think of this as being in order to avoid implementations needing to be smart enough to apply that line of reasoning and prove that there's nothing capable of modifying `var1`: all it has to look at is the type, not the intervening code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's OK. It's part of C and C++ standards. A constant object can be initialized with a non-const object. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm... downvote? Can you please provide a quote from the standard which says this isn't OK? :)